# Running python file in cmd through java- %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: java, python, runtime

I am trying to execute python code with java. My code:

```
public class PyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python src\\gui.py");
    }
}
```

Stack trace:
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "src\gui.py": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

I know, that this error is present while executing python code with 32-bit version interpreter on 64-bit machine. However on my 64-bit machine are installed only 64-bit versions of python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the command shell that knows how to run files by file extension, so you need to invoke the `cmd.exe` Windows shell program:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c python src\\gui.py");
```

As the javadoc of [`exec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String:A-java.io.File-) says, the preferred way to run commands is [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), so your code should be:

```
new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "python", "src\\gui.py").start();
```

You can even change the working directory with that:

```
new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "python", "gui.py")
        .directory(new File("src"))
        .start();
```